# Creating a Ruby Script to Convert Word Document Contents to a Text File

Tags: ruby, text, ms-word

At work, I have two Word documents that represent differing versions of the same documents. I want to compare and extract the differences and I think I want to convert the word document to a text file and then diff it. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Will stripping all tags do the job? Post some example of the before and after of the processing you want to accomplish.

Comment: i suppose it's the 'extract' part of your requirements that go beyond Word's built-in compare tools ~once you've got the xml, a more boring alternative to haxking up a ruby, might make use of the likes of [diff](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_diff.htm) if you have access to cygwin/linux.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Word installed in the system, you might use the activeX Word automation object to extract the text. Use this simple, non-tested, code to get you started

```
word = WIN32OLE.new('Word.Application');
worddoc = word.Documents.Open(filename);
text = worddoc.content.text;
```

If you don't have Word or don't want to require your users to have Word installed, then you might as well extract the text with a little more effort. The recent .docx format that word uses, is nothing more than Open XML Office files in a zip archive. So, you just need to unzip the .docx file, search in the word folder for the xml file representing the document contents; and extract the text simply by parsing the XML (DOM or SAX or PORO or ..).